# How to parse the Google search result in a specific date range?

Tags: java, search, jsoup, google-search, google-custom-search

To set the search result only in a range of date , there are 2 ways of method :

1) Adding the google search keyword with google search operator

&

2) Modelling the url(adding the suffix) .

In my Java application ,I would like to scrape the google news search results (links & title) in a specific range of date by JSOUP ,like 2016

However , I tried this 3 ways of method  ,none of them is successful (contain non-2016 results) .Even through I tired this 3 method in google search box (google web site) or adding the url suffix,they cannot spot the 2016 results .

How to fix this?

By adding google search keyword:

> String search = "stackoverflow daterange:2016-01-01..2016-12-31"
>
> String search = "stackoverflow daterange:2457389-2457735"

Adding url:

> +"&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016"

Code:

```
       String google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";

        String search = "stackoverflow daterange:2016-01-01..2016-12-31 "; //using the google search operators (daterange)

        String charset = "UTF-8";

        String news="&tbm=nws";

        String string = google + URLEncoder.encode(search , charset) + news;

        String userAgent = "ExampleBot 1.0 (+http://example.com/bot)"; 

        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.5.1");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1080");
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
     Document document = Jsoup.connect(string+"&start="+(j+0)*10).userAgent(userAgent). ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true).timeout(100000).ignoreContentType(true).get();
    Elements links = document.select( ".r>a");
....}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem and it turns out it's a bug in the 1.10.2 version of JSoup. Head over to https://jsoup.org/download and grab 1.10.3 and it should fix it. All credits to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153184/jonathan-hedley) who answered my question.